# Is it possible to pass in a function into casper.evaluate()?

Tags: javascript, function, phantomjs, casperjs

Is it possible to pass in a function into casper.evaluate()

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    //verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
    pageSettings: {
        loadImage: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
    }
});    
...
casper.then(function(){
    var config = {};
    config.test = function(a, b){
       return a + b;
    }

    var extractInfo = this.evaluate(function(config) {
       return value = config.test(1, 2);
    }, config);
});
```

This is not working, so I am assuming no, but it seems like we should be able to since we can pass other things in like objects and arrays. If I can attach functions to config and pass that in that would be a HUGE benefit to CasperJS.

This way the helper functions could be modularized and separated into different includes etc before I run the scrape making the code super clean!

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not directly possible. The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) says the following:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

## Single functions

JavaScript is of course very dynamic, so you can serialize a function and pass it as a string into the page context. Then you only need to evaluate it in the page context.

Let's take this for example a named (for simplicity) function `add`:

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}
```

You can pass it into the page context as a string:

```
this.evaluate(function(addFun){
    // TODO: parse/evaluate function
}, add.toString());
```

#### [new Function()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function)

```
var addInternal = new Function("a", "b", addFun + "; return add(a, b);");
```

produces

```
var addInternal = function anonymous(a, b) {
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}; return add(a, b);
}
```

#### [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

It's of course easier to simply evaluate the string.

```
eval(addFun)
```

which directly produces `add`.

Closures can also be evaluated with this technique, but you need to provide the references from the outer scopes inside of the page context at the time of `eval`.

## Function libraries

If you want to do bigger utility functions, I would suggest that you look into how CasperJS includes the clientutils.js into each page ([code](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L1225-L1245)).

It is done by having those function in an additional file which can be injected into the page. This can be done synchronously from a local file with [`casper.page.injectJs(filename)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/inject-js.html) or asynchronously from a remote file with [`casper.page.injectJs(filename, callback)`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html).

Of course, CasperJS provides settings so that those are injected into every page with either [`casper.options.clientScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#clientscripts) or [`casper.options.remoteScripts`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#remotescripts).

Comment: Thanks for the response Artjom, I was considering stringifying the function and than un stringify it, kind of like what your doing above. Ill have to try your method and see if it works. The other solution I saw that someone came up with was to create your own  javascript file, and than inject it into their page so you than have access to those functions. I really like that idea but it would be really annoying to develop like that, because it would have to be constantly uploading my js file to the server so it is accessible on the web.

Comment: It wasn't really clear what exactly you wanted to achieve, but I added the way you would do that from additional utility files. You don't need to host them remotely. PhantomJS/CasperJS are perfectly capable of injecting local files into the page context (see edit).